# Re-create iOS folder in react-native project

Tags: react-native

Somewhy `react-native run-ios` command does not work ( Error code 65  ) in my project.
I followed all the instructions I could find on the internet but nothing worked.
After that I thought that maybe the problem is in the `react-native cli` itself and created another app for testing purposes and `react-native run-ios` command worked perfectly.
And my conclusion is that something broke down my iOS configuration of the app.
Is there any way with which I can delete the iOS folder and generate a new one?

Comment: What's the error ? Be more specific then "Doesn't work for me"

Comment: Error code 65..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code 65 don't give too much information... [image: Code 65]

the best thing you can show us is the stack trace of logs from the terminal or xCode

If you want to delete all dependencies / android / ios folders `npx react-native-clean-project` command inside root of your rn project

### [documentation of react-native-clean-project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clean-project)

Comment: And after deleting these folders is there any way to re-create them?

Comment: yes run `npx pod-install` & `react-native run-ios`